# alternate methods of computing log change yield different structures

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, logging

Can anyone explain why the second method of computing log change yields a numpy array, discarding the index instead of DataFrame? If I specify DataFrame I get one with integer based index.  The first method works as desired. Thanks for any insight.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
aapl = pdr.get_data_yahoo('AAPL')
close = pd.DataFrame(aapl['Close'])
change = np.log(close['Close'] / close['Close'].shift(1))
another_change = np.diff(np.log(close['Close']))
```

Comment: for a simple example, are you asking why for some `x = pd.Series(range(5))`, `np.log(x)` gives you a pandas Series and `np.diff(x)` gives you a numpy array?

Comment: Yes that's right

Comment: I would just ask the simpler question then.  I don't know the answer, but you are more likely to get help with a simple reproducible question that doesn't require someone to `pip install pandas_datareader`

Comment: What is your Pandas and Numpy versions? Your code is working just fine for me (Pandas 0.21, Numpy 1.13.3)

Comment: You mean you get a Series with as the result of both change and another_change? With the date index preserved? I have the same version of numpy and pandas 0.20.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find documentation to back this up, but it seems that the type returned is being converted to `ndarray` when there's a reduction in dimension from the `Series` input. This happens with `diff` but not with `log`.

Taking the simple example:

```
x = pd.Series(range(5))

change = np.log(x / x.shift(1)) # Series of float64 of length 5

another_change = np.diff(np.log(x)) # array of float64 of length 4
```

We can observe that `x / x.shift(1)` is still a 5-element Series (even though elements 0 and 1 are `NaN` and `inf`)  So `np.log`, which doesn't reduce dimension, will still return a 5-element something, which matches the dimensionality of `x`.

However, `np.diff` does reduce dimension -- it is **supposed to** return (according to [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html))

> **diff** : *ndarray*
>   The n-th differences. The shape of the output is the same as a except along axis where the dimension is smaller by n. [...]

The next sentence appears in the above doc for numpy 1.13 but not [1.12](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) and earlier:

> [...] The type of the output is the same as that of the input.

So the type of the output is still an array-like structure, but because of the dimension being reduced, perhaps it doesn't get re-converted to a Series (the array-like input).  At least in versions 1.12 and earlier.

That's my best guess.